# How to assign a part-of-LinkedList at the end of another LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to create two Linked Lists similar to the following picture:

[image]

I can do this using my custom linked list Class like:

```
static class Node { 

    int data; 
    Node next; 

    Node(int d) 
    { 
        data = d; 
        next = null; 
    } 
}
```

My question is can I achieve the same through Java LinkedList Class, like:

```
   List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 15, 30));
   List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9));
```

**How can I link a part of list1 with list2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a `LinkedList`. It is *implemented* using a doubly-linked list, but it doesn't let you access the internals like this.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` is rather useless; it doesn't let you modify the node structure of it at all. You cannot do what you ask, with java.util.LinkedList.

Comment: I'd happily upvote were it not for the first sentence.